# Java- Swagger 404 not found error -Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I am writing a code which belows here. I coudnt manage to reach http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html but i dont knpw why.

Here is mine xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>kodlamaio</groupId>
    <artifactId>northwind</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>northwind</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my Northwind code is below here:

```
package kodlamaio.northwind;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class NorthwindApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NorthwindApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("kodlamaio.northwind"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Console is working but I guess I have problem with Springboot version. Consel output:
[image]

I am adding my folder structure too:
[image]

I changed the version of my swagger but it didnt work. Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: please try https://springdoc.org/v2/ in advance to ("archived") springfox*

Comment: @xerx593 i added the getting started code part but it didnt worked actually. Could you be more clear how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'll suggest to use only one dependency which is 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui' and no additional configuration is needed so you can remove the ```@Bean``` code from your main class. springdoc.org/v2/#spring-webmvc-support

Comment: Can you show your full error message?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @dcm50 in comments, instead of springfox go for springdoc dependency. You just need to add following dependency as you are using Spring Boot v3

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
         <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And if you have spring security enabled whitelist swagger endpoints to not use authentication

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/v3/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll();
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        }).httpBasic();
        return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

Swagger endpoints should be available at these endpoints

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html -- swagger-ui
http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.yaml      -- for yaml doc
http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs          -- for json format
```